# Avoid handling invalid codepoint in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the following SQL code in order to decode UTF-8 chars in Big query:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DecodeUnicode(s STRING) AS (
  (SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('0x', x) AS INT64)))
   FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(s, '\\u')) AS x
   WHERE x != '' 
  )
);
WITH normal AS (
select '\\u05DE\\u05EA\\u05DE\\u05D8\\u05D9\\u05E7\\u05D4123' as edited
), uchars AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
c,
DecodeUnicode(c) uchar
FROM normal,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(edited, r'(\\u[ABCDEF0-9]{4,8})')) c
)
SELECT
 edited,
 STRING_AGG(IFNULL(uchar, x), '' ORDER BY pos) decoded
 FROM(
   SELECT 
   edited, 
   pos,
   SUBSTR(edited, 
   SUM(CASE char WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 6 END) 
     OVER(PARTITION BY edited ORDER BY pos) - CASE char WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 5 END, 
  CASE char WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 6 END) x,
  uchar
  FROM normal ,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(edited, r'(\\u[ABCDEF0-9]{4,8})|.')) char WITH 
  OFFSET AS pos  LEFT JOIN uchars u ON u.c = char
 )
GROUP BY edited
```

The problem is that some of the values I'm handling are not valid when using the function above ('DecodeUnicode')
 - for example this part 'u05D4123' is not charbase valid.
What can I change in my code that when I have such values the function will not handle it and therefore I will not get the 'Invalid codepoint' Error that I get now?

Answer (score 1):

One of the option is to use `SAFE.CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING` instead of `CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING`  but then you still will need to eliminate not handled code from result - for example using regexp as it is in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DecodeUnicode(s STRING) AS (
  (SELECT SAFE.CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('0x', x) AS INT64)))
   FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(s, '\\u')) AS x
   WHERE x != '' 
  )
);
WITH normal AS (
SELECT '\\u05DE\\u05EA\\u05DE\\u05D8\\u05D9\\u05E7\\u05D4123' AS edited
), uchars AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
c,
DecodeUnicode(c) uchar
FROM normal,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(edited, r'(\\u[ABCDEF0-9]{4,8})')) c
)
SELECT
 edited,
 STRING_AGG(IFNULL(uchar, x), '' ORDER BY pos) decoded, 
 REGEXP_REPLACE(STRING_AGG(IFNULL(uchar, x), '' ORDER BY pos) ,r'\\u[ABCDEF0-9]{4,8}', '') decoded_and_fixed
 FROM(
   SELECT 
   edited, 
   pos,
   SUBSTR(edited, 
   SUM(CASE char WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 6 END) 
     OVER(PARTITION BY edited ORDER BY pos) - CASE char WHEN '' THEN 0 ELSE 5 END, 
  CASE char WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 6 END) x,
  uchar
  FROM normal ,
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(edited, r'(\\u[ABCDEF0-9]{4,8})|.')) char WITH 
  OFFSET AS pos  LEFT JOIN uchars u ON u.c = char
 )
GROUP BY edited
```

with result

```
Row edited                                          decoded        decoded_and_fixed     
1   \u05DE\u05EA\u05DE\u05D8\u05D9\u05E7\u05D4123   מתמטיק\u05D4    מתמטיק
```